# Typescript what is the type to pass for lazy import

Tags: typescript, lazy-loading

I am new to typescript and I can't figure out how to solve this problem. I have some lazy imports in multiple files, and I want to wrap them all with a `React.Suspense`, so I thought that the best solution was this one:

*generic .ts file with lazy imports*

```
import Loadable from './Loadable'
import { lazy } from 'react'

const WrappedComponent = Loadable(lazy(() => import('path/to/my/component')));

...
// using wrapped component, for example:
// return <WrappedCompnent />
...
```

*Loadable.tsx*

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Loader from './Loader';

const Loadable = (child: JSX.Element) => (props: object) => {
    const Component = child;
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
            <Component {...props} />
        </Suspense>
    );
}

export default Loadable;
```

I tried to put a lot of thing in place of `JSX.Element` but I keep getting these errors:

```
Argument of type 'LazyExoticComponent<() => Element>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
const WrappedComponent = Loadable(lazy(() => import('path/to/my/component')));
```

and

```
JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
<Component {...props} />
```

What do I have to put in place of `JSX.Element` to make it work?

 Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have a look at [https://loadable-components.com/](https://loadable-components.com/)? What you are trying to implement seems to be their `loadable` function. You can use the package or check the source code to see how they implemented it.

Comment: @colinD thank you, but it does not help in my case. I have multiple files like the _generic.ts_ I posted, in multiple folders...I wanted to avoid the import of `Loader` in each of them, I would like to have the import and the `fallback` parameter in a single place (_Loadable.tsx_) that takes as a parameter the result of the lazy import and wraps it with the fallback. In the examples of the package like [this](https://loadable-components.com/docs/fallback/) they always do it in the same file...what I want to do is passing the result of lazy imports from multiple files to _Loadable.tsx_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const Loadable = (child: JSX.Element) => (props: object) => {
```

`JSX.Element` is not the right type for the `child` argument.  A React component is a function (or class) that takes a props object and *returns* a `JSX.Element` (or `null`).  So `JSX.Element` describes the return type of the component rather than the component itself.

The type for a React component is `ComponentType<P>` where `P` is the type for the props.

We are dealing with `React.lazy` imports so we need another is another layer of wrapping on the types.  Your `child` argument is not a component but rather it is a `lazy` import of a component.

The type for a `lazy` component is `LazyExoticComponent<T extends ComponentType<any>>` where `T` is the type of the component.  If you have props `P` you would use `LazyExoticComponent<ComponentType<P>>`.

You don't really know the type `P` of the component's props because it is different for each component that you wrap.  You are currently using a vague type `object` but that won't give you good type support.

We can use a generic type `P` to describe the props of the inner/`child` component.  That way the `WrappedComponent` will have the correct props type based on the type of the component that it is wrapping.

That brings us to:

```
const Loadable = <P extends object>(
    child: React.LazyExoticComponent<React.ComponentType<P>>
) => (props: P) => {
```

Which is pretty close, but it will give you an error about refs:

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithRef<P & { children?: ReactNode; }>'.
```

Your higher-order component does not forward refs therefore we need to specify in the types that the returned `WrappedComponent` does not accept a `ref` prop.  We can do that with another built-in React type `PropsWithoutRef`.

```
const Loadable = <P extends object>(
    child: React.LazyExoticComponent<React.ComponentType<P>>
) => (props: React.PropsWithoutRef<P>) => {
```

You can import the types instead of using `React.TypeName`. That looks like:

```
import { lazy, Suspense, LazyExoticComponent, PropsWithoutRef, ComponentType } from 'react';

const Loadable = <P extends object>(
    child: LazyExoticComponent<ComponentType<P>>
) => (props: PropsWithoutRef<P>) => {
```

Comment: I get two errors doing this. First one: `Type 'PropsWithoutRef<P>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<Component<P, any, any>>) | PropsWithRef<P>)'.` and then there is a stack of other messages...the last one is `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.` (please tell me if you need more info). Second error: `Spread types may only be created from object types.`

Comment: Ah yes I am seeing that now in the TS playground.  It was fine in the environment where I was working on it.  The `Spread types may only be created from object types` error only happens in TS 4.7+.  Both errors go away for me if I change the `P extends any` to `P extends object`.  Does that do it for you too?  It could also be `P extends Record<string, unknown>`.

Comment: with `P extends object` it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a thin abstraction around `loadable` from the `@loadable/component` library, so the `Loader` component is only imported once.

The typing is from the library itself.

```js
import loadable, {
  DefaultComponent,
  LoadableComponent,
} from "@loadable/component";
import React from "react";

const Loader = () => <div>Loading...</div>;

const Loadable = <TProps,>(
  loadFn: (props: TProps) => Promise<DefaultComponent<TProps>>
): LoadableComponent<TProps> =>
  loadable(loadFn, { fallback: <Loader /> });

export default Loadable;
```

Then in another file:

```js
import Loadable from "./Loadable";

const OtherComponent = Loadable(() => import("path/to/component"));

const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <OtherComponent /* props for OtherComponent */ />
    </div>
  );
}
```